# Change Order of user profile properties above "Show More" link in User profile page (Person.aspx)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, my-site, user-profile-property

I want to change the order of user profile properties above "Show More" link. As i know we can change the order under "Show More" link using PowerShell. My Question is how we can change the order of properties that are above "Show More" link ? See picture below;

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this can be done oob with a custom app part. You could try using some javascript to write some render logic. This blog may give some info on the DOM properties: http://www.sharepointgalaxy.com/2013/04/sharepoint-2013-user-profile-page-profile-properties-section-show-more-by-default/

Comment: I have seen this blog. But where i add this css code? In which page?

Comment: It says on the blog that its set as an alternate css file in the My Site master page